# Using CollapsingToolbarLayout without setSupportActionBar cause wrong collapsed title position

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, androiddesignsupport

Like the title said, if using toolbar without setSupportActionBar in activity, when the toolbar is collapsed, the title of toolbar will have a strange top padding, and this padding is 24dp height, which is the height of the statusbar.

The screenshot:
[image: Collapsing issue screenshot]

But if I add `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` to Activity's onCreate, then this problem resolved.

The layout file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:title="test"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I'm just using the sample ScrollActivity without big modification, just add a app:title to Toolbar, and comment out `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

the version of design library is 27.1.1

Comment: have you tried removing ` android:fitsSystemWindows="true" ` from  the root coordinator layout

Comment: yes, remove this line do the trick, but it also makes your View inside CollapsingToolbarLayout can't overlap the statusBar, which is what I needed too.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I worked out this problem but just don't get the reason why Google do this.

In the onLayout method of CollapsingToolbarLayout, it will first calculate toolbar's collapsed title's position

```
final int maxOffset = getMaxOffsetForPinChild(
                        mToolbarDirectChild != null ? mToolbarDirectChild : mToolbar);
                ViewGroupUtils.getDescendantRect(this, mDummyView, mTmpRect);
                mCollapsingTextHelper.setCollapsedBounds(
                        mTmpRect.left + (isRtl
                                ? mToolbar.getTitleMarginEnd()
                                : mToolbar.getTitleMarginStart()),
                        mTmpRect.top + maxOffset + mToolbar.getTitleMarginTop(),
                        mTmpRect.right + (isRtl
                                ? mToolbar.getTitleMarginStart()
                                : mToolbar.getTitleMarginEnd()),
                        mTmpRect.bottom + maxOffset - mToolbar.getTitleMarginBottom());
```

and the maxOffset is calculated at `getMaxOffsetForPinChild`, which is as follows:

```
final int getMaxOffsetForPinChild(View child) {
    final ViewOffsetHelper offsetHelper = getViewOffsetHelper(child);
    final LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
    return getHeight()
            - offsetHelper.getLayoutTop()
            - child.getHeight()
            - lp.bottomMargin;
}
```

the problem is, offsetHelper.getLayoutTop() will first returns 0 instead of the real top 24dp, because at this time, offsetHelper's onViewLayout has not got called, it will be called after calculating collapsed title position.

```
    // Update our child view offset helpers. This needs to be done after the title has been
    // setup, so that any Toolbars are in their original position
    for (int i = 0, z = getChildCount(); i < z; i++) {
        getViewOffsetHelper(getChildAt(i)).onViewLayout();
    }
```

and according to the comment, this is the intend behavior, onViewLayout must be called after the title has been setup.**This is the point I don't get.**

I guess setSupportActionBar did something make onLayout get called again, which will recalculate the title's position with the right LayoutTop. So I add the following code:

```
    final CollapsingToolbarLayout v = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
    v.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            v.requestLayout();
        }
    });
```

to the activity's onCreate method, and problem solved.

Now, I'll leave this question open since I don't think this is a elegant solution and maybe there is some offical method to solve this problem. Or is this a bug Android dev don't aware?